# My Remove Method isn't Working

Tags: java

Create a program that keeps track of the following information input by the user:

`First Name`, `Last Name`, `Phone Number`, `Age`

Now - let's store this in a multidimensional array that will hold 10 of these contacts.
So our multidimensional array will need to be 10 rows and 4 columns.
You should be able to add, display and remove contacts in the array.
*/

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class compLab2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String[][] contacts = new String [10][4]; 
        System.out.println("Select your options: \n");

        while(true){
            // Give the user a list of their options
            System.out.println("1: Add a new contact to list.");
            System.out.println("2: Remove a contact from the list.");
            System.out.println("3: Display contacts.");
            System.out.println("0: Exit the list.");

            // Get the user input
            int userChoice = input.nextInt();

            switch(userChoice){
                case 1:             
                    addContacts(contacts);
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    removeContacts(contacts);
                    break;

                case 3: 
                    displayContacts(contacts);
                    break;

                case 0: 
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addContacts (String [][] contacts) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (contacts[i][0] == null || contacts[i][0].equals(null)) {
                contacts[i][0] = input.nextLine();
                contacts[i][1] = input.nextLine();
                contacts[i][2] = input.nextLine();
                contacts[i][3] = input.nextLine();
                boolean Inserted = true;
                break;
            }
        }            
    }

    private static void removeContacts(String [][] contacts) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the contact you want to remove: ");
        String removeContact = input.nextLine();
        for(int i=0; i<contacts.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j <contacts[i].length; j++){
                if(contacts[i][j].equals(removeContact)) {
                    contacts[i][0]=" "; 
                    contacts[i][1]=" "; 
                    contacts[i][2]=" ";
                    contacts[i][3]=" "; 
                }
            }
            break;                  
       }
   }

   private static void displayContacts(String [][] contacts) {
       for (int i = 0; i< contacts.length; i++) {
           for (int j= 0; j < contacts[i].length; j++) {
               System.out.print(contacts[i][j] + " ");
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: for me your code is working. In which scenario its not working? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: remove method only works for the first row. It doesn't work for other rows. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: I just wanted to mention that your instruction to the user: "Enter the name of the contact you want to remove: ", is contradicting. You can also enter the phone number or age to get the entry removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to move your break inside the if condition(once element is remove break the loop) otherwise your first for loop will break in i=0 condition.
- In if condition you have to check `removeContact` with `contacts[i][j]` because `contacts[i][j]` can be null.

Below you can find the code

```
    if (removeContact != null) { //removeContact should not be null
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < contacts[i].length; j++) {
                if (removeContact.equals(contacts[i][j])) { //removeContact is not null so check removeContact with contacts[i][j]
                    contacts[i][0] = " ";
                    contacts[i][1] = " ";
                    contacts[i][2] = " ";
                    contacts[i][3] = " ";
                    break; //break the loop once you remove
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `null` insteam of `white space(" ")`

```
if (removeContact != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < contacts[i].length; j++) {
            if (removeContact.equals(contacts[i][j])) {
                contacts[i][0] = null;
                contacts[i][1] = null;
                contacts[i][2] = null;
                contacts[i][3] = null;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because you are checking null while adding a contact. So setting null will free a space in your array and will allow you to add a new contact to that space.

Also you should check null entry during displaying contacts

```
private static void displayContacts(String [][] contacts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i][0] != null) {
            for (int j= 0; j < contacts[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(contacts[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

An `ArrayList` with a custom class can solve this problem easily.